# How to arrange the figure along the line itself?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment

How to arrange the figure along the line itself?

[image]

My picture must be along the question itself. How to do that?? help me.

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight
9.2in \textwidth 6.5in
%\hoffset -1in
%\voffset -1in
%\evensidemargin 14pt
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,dsfont,multicol}
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{.bmp}{bmp}{.bb}{}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
 \question In the adjoining figure, $AC=$

  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{./triangle}
     \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the figure environment and centering.

Comment: No.. thats not working..@Jesse

Comment: You can use ctr-G (or an image icon on top) to include your image in you edit window.

Comment: either your image has white spaces around it or use \raisebox{-20pt}{content} to adjust your image up or down. + for up, - for down.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight
9.2in \textwidth 6.5in
%\hoffset -1in
%\voffset -1in
%\evensidemargin 14pt
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,dsfont,multicol}
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{.bmp}{bmp}{.bb}{}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
 \question In the adjoining figure, $AC=$ \quad
 %\begin{figure}[h]
% \centering
 \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
% \end{figure}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: file:///home/david/Desktop/error1.jpg
its comming lile this only.

Comment: how to upload the figure in command box originall?@Jesse

Answer (score 0):

The blank line between the `\question` line and the `\includegraphics` line means that the graphic is in a separate paragraph.

Remove the blank line and you should get the desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight
9.2in \textwidth 6.5in
%\hoffset -1in
%\voffset -1in
%\evensidemargin 14pt
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,dsfont,multicol}
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{.bmp}{bmp}{.bb}{}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
 \question In the adjoining figure, $AC=$
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{./triangle}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}
```